# Does std::regex support "(?i)" for case insensitivity?

Tags: c++, regex

I am using Visual Studio 2010.  This...

`std::regex pattern("(?i).*a.*");`

...throws this...

`std::tr1::regex_error - regular expression error`

...and I can't find anything that says if `std::regex` supports the `(?i)` syntax for case insensitivity or not.

Can anyone confirm/deny that `(?i)` is not supported as a prefix for case insensitivity by `std::regex`?

Comment: You may want to tell which implementation you are using, and which regex flavor you expect it to be using.

Comment: @zneak I have added to the post that I use VS2010.  I'm not sure which flavor I am expecting.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The standard only requires conformance to the POSIX regular expression syntax (which does not include Perl extensions like this one) and conformance to the ECMAScript regular expression specification (with minor exceptions, per ISO 14882-2011§28.13), which is described in ECMA-262, §15.10.2. ECMAScript's regular expression grammar *does not* include the use of modifiers in the form of the `(?)` syntax, so, by extension, neither does C++11/14, nor do most implementations of TR1.

That does not preclude your standard library from implementing more PCRE extensions, but the standard does not require it, so it's simply not guaranteed.

So, no, it's not supported, *per se.*

You can, however declare your regular expression as follows:

```
std::regex pattern(".*a.*", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

This will declare your pattern to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

[boost::regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) supports Perl syntax, which has `(?i)`.